# Python Matplot animation embedding in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm currently working on a visualisation of different sorting algorithms and am now attempting to embed the animations in a tkinker gui for ease of use. The animations are done with matplotlib and use bar charts. I'm currently struggling to get the graphs to be animated. I had it working without the gui but currently I get a static graph in the gui. Please could I have some advice on how to rectify this. Full code so far can be found at https://github.com/MGedney1/Sorting_Algorithm_Visualisation

Area of interest code:

```py
import random
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame,Label,Entry,Button

def bubble_sort(lst):        #Bubble Sort
    index = len(lst) - 1
    while index >= 0:
        test_index = index
        while test_index >= 0:
            if lst[index] < lst[test_index]:
                temp = lst[index]
                lst[index] = lst[test_index]
                lst[test_index] = temp
            test_index -= 1
            yield lst
        index -= 1

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.set_up_window()

    def update_fig(self):        #Update fig function
        for self.rect, val in zip(self.rects,self.unordered):     #Setting height of the rectangles
            self.rect.set_height(val)
        self.iteration[0] += 1
        text.set_text("# of operations: {}".format(iteration[0]))

    def set_up_window(self):
        n,self.unordered = create_array()
        title = 'Test'
        generator = bubble_sort(self.unordered)


        self.fig,self.ax = plt.subplots()        #Creating axis and figure

        self.bar_rects = self.ax.bar(range(len(self.unordered)), self.unordered, align="edge")      #Creating the rectangular bars

        self.ax.set_xlim(0, n)       #Axis limits
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, int(1.07 * n))

        self.text = self.ax.text(0.02, 0.95, "", transform=self.ax.transAxes)      #Number of operations counter

        self.iteration = [0]

        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, func=self.update_fig, frames=generator, interval=1,repeat=False)       #Creating the animatio

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=root)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("700x400")
    app = Window(root)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you mean `update_fig` to be a static method, or do you need a `self` in there? `def update_fig(self, unordered, rects, iteration):`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the function to take the self parameter but still have the same issue.